# Help With Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I want to fetch data from sales cloud but the field i am using is date filed with the format : `MM/DD/YYYY.`

The query i am using in marketing cloud activity looks like :

```
Select * from Contact_Salesforce WHERE BirthdayCurrentYear__c = GETDATE()
```

Records are coming into my sync data extension but not in standard data extension.

May be its due to the date format and `"BirthdayCurrentYear__c"` this is the formula field in sales cloud.

Please suggest the best way to write a query so my sales cloud data will come into marketing cloud data extension.

Comment: Can you please confirm if your standard DE has all the fields as compared to your standard DE? Also, is BirthdayCurrentYear__c a date field or a text field? and can you show me an example of the value in this field?

Comment: BirthdayCurrentYear__c  field is a formula field with date data type in sales cloud and sync DE and standard DE has same field.

Comment: sure. are you trying to query the current year birthdays or birthday which falls today?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two things.

1. Ensure the DE has a primary key
2. `GetDate()` will have `hh:mm:ss` in addition. You may need to try a query where it's only for a specific day, since you are using `=`. If the `hh:mm:ss` aren't matching, then the query won't work.